# “A mirror” and “mirror” (without “a”)

Tags: articles

An apple is ground or sliced, “an” can be omitted.

There’s apple, watermelon, melon, etc.

If a mirror is broken or shattered, can “a” be omitted?

There’s mirror.

Comment: Apples can be chopped, cooked, pureed, and if raw grated or sliced. You ground (*mince* in BrEng) meat, seeds, grains, and even coconut but not apples.

Comment: @Mari-LouA If one passes apples through a device with a similar sort of action to [the one used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meat_grinder) to make ground (BrEng minced) meat (e.g. to prepare the apples for a cider press) in AmEng it would be acceptable to use the verb "to grind" for the process, and the adjective "ground" to describe the result. (It's a grinder. It grinds things. They come out ground.) It's not normally done with apples, so it's not a common usage, but not one objectionable enough to make comment.

Comment: @R.M. Thank you, I had not thought about the possibility of making apple juice / cider. Still it is worthwhile pointing out that "ground apple" is uncommon in speech and in recipes, as you also mentioned.

Comment: @Mari-LouA "ground apple" is uncommon in speech and in recipes - Not in French, Dutch, Danish, etc. "Pommes frites" are not fried *apples*!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sacrilege! Making cider is the only thing apples are good for. Eating them is just a waste of good fermentation material.

Comment: "*An apple is ground or sliced, “an” can be omitted.*"  As a native speaker of English, I *strongly* dispute that assertion.  Or you need to give more detail in your question than four terse lines.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Some nouns like "apple" and "watermelon" are sometimes count nouns, and sometimes non-count nouns, depending on *how we're thinking about them*, not whether they're solid or broken.

When we're thinking of individual pieces of fruit, "apple" and "watermelon" are count nouns:

> *I have **an apple** in my lunch.*
>
> *We almost ate **a** whole **watermelon***.

When we think of them as ingredients or a general substance, they are non-count nouns:

> *This pie needs more **apple**.*
>
> *There's **watermelon** all over the lawn.*

With "mirror", generally speaking, when it's broken, we don't think of it as a mirror anymore because it doesn't reflect images, so it's not a mirror. We think about it as a general substance:

> "*Our living room mirror broke, and now there's **glass** all over the carpet.*"

Mirrors stop being mirrors when they break, and become glass.

Comment: Broken pieces of mirror are still "mirrors", just smaller pieces. There's glass on the carpet, will first evoke a broken drinking glass, vase or bottle not a mirror.

Comment: "Use those broken pieces of mirror to create a very unique and very lovely tabletop", "In the second stage, the pieces of mirror are now arranged in three different geometrical shapes (See Figures 7, 8 and 9).", "I Googled broken glass jewelry, so this would work for most pieces of mirror.", "In Chehel Sotun palace in addition to vertical mirrors, smaller pieces of mirror were used to decorate the ceiling"

Comment: You could say "there are bits of mirror all over the carpet" and that would be idiomatic, but "there's mirror" would still be strange. So it's kind of middle-ground.

Comment: @hobbs I would view "there's mirror all over the carpet" as being a deliberately comedic subversion of the usual. That is, it does sound strange, but definitely within the realm of possibility of things someone might say if they're not being too serious :)

Comment: "there's mirror all over the carpet" would certainly not be used formally but I could see it in a poem or a song lyric, possibly when describing a very surreal or abstract scene. See also "are we Dancer?" as a lyric. It's definitely not grammatically correct because as this answer states it is not an uncounted noun.

Comment: @Rodney I'm a bit puzzled, the OP asks if "There's mirror." is acceptable, and it seems nearly everyone agrees! If they were writing an essay for an English language exam, the examiner might believe the indefinite article was forgotten, because without context that phrase is peculiar to say the least. "There's glass" OK "There's table" NO even if that table is made of wood, it's still ungrammatical.

Comment: I would consider the parts of the mirror to still be part of the whole. "The mirror was shattered across the carpet." or "Mirror fragments were all over the carpet" I wouldn't consider each piece to be a mirror unto itself unless it was explicitly used for that purpose. An example is the mirror in deathly hallows, which is most often referred to as a fragment of the mirror or a shard of a mirror.

Comment: @hobbs: But if you came in later, you wouldn't know if those bits of mirror on the carpet were from a mirror or several mirrors.

Comment: @SebastianSimon it *should* be, "We ate *almost* a whole watermelon."

Comment: A mirror is not pure glass - it's glass coated with a reflective metal on one side. So, it makes sense to refer to the pieces as "mirror shards", rather than "broken glass".

Comment: @Stef, agreed. You could also say "mirrored glass", since that's what most mirrors are. And as others say, while it would be a bit odd to refer to broken mirror shards as a mirror, it is totally acceptable to refer to a mirror in a makeup compact as a mirror, which might be smaller than some of the broken pieces, so context matters and English is just weird. ;-)

Comment: It might be worth discussing separately but here,  the fact that shards of a broken mirror can still function as individual mirrors is a distraction.

Baldly, "apple" can be a count and a non-count noun and "mirror" can't. That's why context allows either "some apple" or "some bits of apple" but never "some mirror" except in the humorous examples above.

Specifically "an apple" chopped or stewed becomes generically "apple." We can freely choose whether to use the full "chopped/ stewed apple" but that's a different point.

Answer (score 9):

You could potentially use "*you've got mirror all over the floor*" as a humorous/slang-like expression ("*you've got*" in this sentence meaning "*you have caused there to be*").

As explained by other answers, it isn't grammatically correct English but it does have a comical aspect to it, perhaps even invoking surreal connotations (think Salvador Dalí's *Persistence of Memory* painting).

Comment: Definite +1 on this; wordplay on this nature (deliberately mixing up countable and uncountable, etc) is common.

Answer (score 5):

There are pieces of the mirror on ground, and the mirror is a specific object
which is shattered. Thereby, "the" has to be added in front of mirror.
or
Broken mirrors can be described as pieces of the mirror

Comment: No, that’s not what I’m wondering about.

Comment: As my examples show, it is not absolutely necessary to add the definite article "the" between "of" and "mirror" to make *There are pieces of the mirror*…. However, the article *is* essential before the noun *ground*, i.e. “*There are pieces of mirror on **the** ground*” See my and Geoff Davids' answer which have ***the floor***.

Answer (score 3):

- ***There's an apple**, avocado and a watermelon*.

One of each fruit. If there is more than one piece of fruit the plural verb "are" should be used.

- ***There are apples,** avocados and watermelons.*

The same principle applies to a mirror which is a countable noun

- ***There's a mirror** on the table*

More than one mirror becomes

- ***There are three mirrors** on the table*

If *one* of the three mirrors falls and breaks…

- ***There are bits/pieces of mirror** on the floor*
- *There's **a** broken **mirror***

From the net

- *…for diamonds are bought and worn for the same reason that magpies assume unto themselves such things **as bits of** tin **and broken mirror glass** simply because they glitter, and glitter more than any other substance.*
- *He took **the broken pieces of mirror** and began to fit them onto the entrance wall, one piece at a time, as though he were constructing a mosaic.*
- *Lil kneels on the floor and picks up the **broken pieces of mirror***
- *Moreover , the young dancers are dressed in costumes made up of **bits of mirror** which "flash and sparkle as they move"*

Mirror and glass are not the same, the former is countable while the latter, a substance, is uncountable. So while the phrase "There's glass…" is grammatical, the same cannot be said for "There's mirror” even when that object is broken or shattered (into pieces).

See the [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20broken%20mirror%2Cpieces%20of%20mirror%2Cthere%27s%20mirror&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20broken%20mirror%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpieces%20of%20mirror%3B%2Cc0) chart below

[image]

Comment: I would disagree that "there's mirror all over the floor" is ungrammatical.  It's unusual, but not ungrammatical, regardless of the semantics of the word "mirror".  The general principle of turning a count noun into a mass noun, particularly in order to emphasise that it's been damaged, is a productive one.  See for instance the example due to the linguist Ronald Langacker at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Langacker#Quotes/examples: "After I ran over the cat with our car, there was cat all over the driveway".  It has a tone of grim humour, and the wording is unusual, but grammatical.

Comment: @tea-and-cake would you tell an English learner that "There's table" is grammatical because it's become a mass noun when it is smashed or damaged?

Comment: Yes, if they asked if it was grammatical, I certainly wouldn't tell them it was ungrammatical. I'd explain why it was grammatical, and tell them when they'd hear it and what connotations it has, as has indeed been done in other answers.

Comment: @tea-and-cake  But gotube's answer *never* says *There's mirror* is grammatical, they changed the word to *glass* claiming a mirror is no longer a mirror when it is broken but becomes glass. Your example of a cat's dead body being crushed under the wheels of a car, is still a "cat", the noun doesn't change into *bones and blood*. There's only one answer that clearly says *There's mirror on the floor* is acceptable if it were constructed as *You've got mirror on the floor*, and I'd agree with that usage but for me it remains distinctly different from *There's mirror*....

Comment: I was referring not to gotube's answer, but to Geoff's, which talks about the connotations.  You may well consider _There's mirror all over the floor_ ungrammatical, but your justifications are based on semantics and context, not grammar.  I disagree, and am happy to see a count noun used as a mass noun, which is a marked, jocular, but recognised and grammatical usage -- as, it seems, is Langacker, who appears to be the only linguist cited in response to the question.  We'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: I was referring to `as has indeed been done in other answers`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other excellent answers - I would note that nouns and even proper nouns are sometimes used informally as non-count nouns for comedic effect.

For example:

> My car exploded! Now there's car all over the road.